# Referrer URL appears to be pointing to a naughty picture

Tags: referrer, referrer-spam

This may belong on Serverfault, but I don't think so.

I have a website with the archives of a local radio program that had some cult following in Australia, and may have a limited, but active, group of visitors

I have noticed in my logs, the referrer URL of 4 unique visits appear to come from a path beta.hustler.com/photos/images/ (and some more ...)

I'm sure no one at hustler would care about my dinky little Australian fansite, and don't know why a true referral URL would originate from Hustler, especially an image directory.

Would this just a new form of Spam, some proxied referral or something more nefarious?

Comment: What are the referrers loading? e.g. it is very common to hotlink to images.

Comment: No, it's just page views on an mp3 listing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referrers are easy to spoof.  They are trying to get the attention of webmasters by putting bogus referrers in their requests to your site, so that the referrer goes into the log, and you notice them.

Comment: That is a very pathetic form of spam, not that I know many non-pathetic forms